# Installing Apache Hive on Windows without using any virtual machine

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, apache-hive

Recently I started to learn about Hive. So I wanted to try hands on but the problem is that I am not getting any tutorial to install hive on windows machine. Constraint i have is that-
1. Cannot install Linux in my machine on side with windows as a dual boot.
2. Cannot install VMware or Virtual box. 
So all i was looking was to play with Hive queries with all these above mentioned constraint/problems.

Comment: Do you have a Hadoop cluster already setup? If not, having a Hive client doesn't do you any good. Alternatively, learning SQL in general, is all you really need

Comment: I have a decent knowledge of SQL. I thought of creating single node cluster with Hadoop over Cygwin like [this](https://sundersinghc.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/running-hadoop-on-cygwin-in-windows-single-node-cluster)

Comment: @sudeep123..then you need to have a hadoop cluster access or hadoop VM on you machine.

Comment: I have a decent knowledge of SQL. I thought of creating single node cluster with Hadoop over Cygwin like [this](https://sundersinghc.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/running-hadoop-on-cygwin-in-windows-single-node-cluster)  @cricket_007

Comment: Okay, so follow those instructions to get Hadoop installed, then find another guide on how to install install/configure Hive. I was just making a point that there is no benefit of running queries against a dataset that is only point in a single node. You might as well get SparkSQL setup instead because that runs the same HiveQL syntax